# Qt6 CMake for QML

Tags: qt, cmake, qml, qtquick2, qt6

I'm working on Qt with CMake.
Is it possible to import runtime QML files using CMake?

I wanto to creare a folder, near the .exe where I can put many QML files.

MyProject

- CMakeLists.txt
- main.cpp
- main.qml
  test_comp
  myComponent
- CMakeLists.txt
- FirstComponent.qml
- SecondComponent.qml

First CMakeLists.txt
[...]
add_subdirectory(test_comp/myComponent)
[...]

MyComponent CMakeLists.txt
qt_add_qml_module(myComponent
URI test_comp.myComponent
VERSION 1.0
PLUGIN_TARGET myComponent
QML_FILES
TabButton.qml
)

With this solution Qt create .dll and .lib files. but If I want to modify my component.qml
I need to rebuild to generate new dll. and .lib files.

Is there a way with CMake to make that qml component workable runtime for my app?

Thanks

Comment: qml is part of the resource file you should add `.qrc` file to your CMake. I didn't understand what is your problem, did you do this?

Comment: Yeah but I want to load my qml file not from my .qrc, but from a path where .qml file is located. So at runtime is I make some chages to my qml I can simply re-run the app